# Is there a way to reassemble smooth terms from mgcv in glmmTMB?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, glmmtmb

I am in need of a ZI genpois model in glmmTMB for my analysis (modelling nested annual bird counts ~ weather covariates). A random slope/intercept glmmTMB model (1 + year | site) cannot resolve the temporal autocorrelation in my time-series data, but a site-varying smooth term on year in mgcv can. Since mgcv does not have a generalized Poisson family, I am trying to import the year smoother into glmmTMB. However, the approach that I am using to do so does not work in the end, as with 31 unique sites, the final glmmTMB is far too overparameterized (>100 parameters for all the basis dimensions of each site-specific smooth, but <400 observations in the input data).

Is there an easier way to convert my s(year, by=site, m=2, bs="cr") smooth in mgcv::gam into a non-penalized smoother (for given, but different edf/knots per site) in glmmTMB?